# NoSuchMethodError : Spark + Kafka : Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

**Use Case**

Simple message fetching and printing from Kafka topic using Spark with Java as programming language

**Background**

- Experience in dealing with Kafka Storm Integration, developed and maintained kafka cluster and storm topologies more than a year.
- No experience with Apache Spark and Scala
- Simple word count application built and tested successfully using stand alone spark cluster.

**Problem**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at com.random.spark.EventsToFileAggregator.main(EventsToFileAggregator.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

At EventsToFileAggregator.java:54

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
 KafkaUtils.createStream(jsc, args[0], args[1], topicMap,
 StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Build**

Successful without any warnings

**Command**

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.random.spark.EventsToFileAggregator --master spark://host:7077 /usr/local/spark/stats/target/stats-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar localhost:2181 test topic 2
```

Comment: This happens with just spark-streaming jobs that have "->" in them, and, apparently, spark-streaming-kafka has it too. Illustrated it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395521/spark-2-0-0-streaming-job-packed-with-sbt-assembly-lacks-scala-runtime-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` is almost always an indication that two libraries are not at a compatible version. In this case Spark-Streaming Kafka is attempting to use a Scala language feature that doesn't exist. Check that the version of Spark-Streaming Kafka is compatible with the version of Scala you're using. Make sure you're not actually running with Scala and not Java.

Comment: Do I require to have scala installed on the machine ? I am not doing anything with Scala here. With same setting simple word count was running fine.

Comment: Yes you do: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc is a Scala thing

Comment: Well, I get that, but why simple application then is running without it ? does "that" part of spark not require scala installed ? The packages used should pull in required dependency and I am packaging jar with dependencies. I changed pm.xml to use 2.10 versions. Error is gone, program is running (?) but not getting desired output, due to `Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

Comment: That's right, it's specifically the Kafka part that's attempting to use Scala. I would recommend asking a new question because I have no idea about that issue :)