# Spark 2.0.0 streaming job packed with sbt-assembly lacks Scala runtime methods

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

When using `->` in Spark Streaming 2.0.0 jobs, or using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11` v2.0.0, and submitting it with `spark-submit`, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 72.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 72.0 (TID 37, localhost): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I put a brief illustration of this phenomenon to a GitHub repo: [spark-2-streaming-nosuchmethod-arrowassoc](https://github.com/utgarda/spark-2-streaming-nosuchmethod-arrowassoc)

Putting only provided dependencies to `build.sbt`

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
```

using `->` anywhere in the driver code, packing it with `sbt-assembly` and submitting the job results in an error. This isn't a big problem by itself, using `ArrayAssoc` can be avoided, but `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11` v2.0.0 has it somewhere inside, and generates the same error.

Doing it like so:

```
wordCounts.map{
  case (w, c) => Map(w -> c)
}.print()
```

Then

```
sbt assembly
```

Then

```
spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount \
--master local[2] \
--deploy-mode client \
./target/scala-2.11/spark-2-streaming-nosuchmethod-arrowassoc-assembly-1.0.jar \
localhost 5555
```

Comment: Do you include Scala in your uber JAR?

Comment: Yep, sbt-assembly includes Scala runtime by default. But to make sure, I also tried requesting it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Spark jobs should be packed without Scala runtime, i.e. , if you're doing it with sbt-assembly, add this: `assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)`
2. I just had my `SPARK_HOME` enviroment variable pointing to Spark 1.6.2, doesn't matter where you run `spark-submit` from, `SPARK_HOME` should be set properly.